# Is there an error-proof way in google sheets to extract House numbers from address cell (street + house number) into another cell

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In `Sheet1!AK2:AK` I have addresses in the following formats:

```
rotenkamper weg, 323, Kirchstieg 2345, Im Schleedörn 20b
```

I need the street names to export into `Sheet2!C3:C`, i.e:

```
rotenkamper weg, Kirchenstieg, Im Schleedörn
```

The House numbers have to go into `Sheet2!D3:D`.

I have researched and tried for hours but couldn't find a solution that could fetch the house numbers including the letter i.e. **20b** or if the number is a range **24-27**.

Also, I have huge trouble to get it to work when the street consist of two or more words.

Does anyone know an elegant solution for this?

Any help would be much appreciated. This will safe me weeks of data entry work.

Comment: Could you share a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on (free of sensitive information), containing the outcome you expect?

Comment: _"an error-proof way in google sheets ...."_ is highly dependent on your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in `Sheet2!C3`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  {
    REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(Sheet1!AK2:AK, "\s+\S*\d\S*\b", ""), ",+", ","),
    IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(Sheet1!AK2:AK, "\S+$"))
  }
)
```

Explanation:

1. `REGEXREPLACE(Sheet1!AK2:AK, "\s+\S*\d\S*\b", "")` this one removes any "word" which has a digit in it. Al of these **323**, **2345**, **20b** will be gone.
2. `REGEXREPLACE(..., ",+", ",")` cleans up any multiple consequent commas which may appear after removing in the first step. This will be a value for the first column.
3. `IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(Sheet1!AK2:AK, "\S+$"))` this one just gets whatever is at the end of the address string from the last space to the end. This will be a value for the second column.
4. `{value_for_the_first_column, value_for_the_second_column}` placed in the `C3` cell will populate `C3` with **value_for_the_first_column** and `D3` with **value_for_the_first_column**.
5. `ARRAYFORMULA` will do all of the above for every row.

---

Regex pattern could be refined if you provide more than one example of the address.

Comment: That worked really well! Thank you. Now i only need to get rid of blank cells. I have done this using filter() and len() in the past. Can you help me incorporate this into this formula? I can't seem to work it out

Comment: Where do you get blanks? From what string? Maybe you could just use `FILTER(Sheet1!AK2:AK, Sheet1!AK2:AK <> "")` instead of just `Sheet1!AK2:AK` inside those formulas?

Comment: the source sheet has blanks between the addresses if one person orders more than one product. like so: https://imgur.com/a/Dldajjq

Comment: FILTER(Sheet1!AK2:AK, Sheet1!AK2:AK <> "" did unfortunately not work it yields #ERROR!

Maybe i Implemented it incorrectly. I did it like so: 

=ARRAYFORMULA(
  {
    REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(FILTER(Sheet1!AK2:AK, Sheet1!AK2:AK <> "", "\s+\S*\d\S*\b", ""), ",+", ","),
    IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(FILTER(Sheet1!AK2:AK, Sheet1!AK2:AK <> "", "\S+$"))
  }
)))

Comment: @FriedemannFrommelt you forgot a parenthesis and Sheets gave you a few extra at the end insted. Should be `=ARRAYFORMULA({REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(FILTER(Sheet1!AK2:AK, Sheet1!AK2:AK <> ""), "\s+\S*\d\S*\b", ""), ",+", ","), IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(FILTER(Sheet1!AK2:AK, Sheet1!AK2:AK <> ""), "\S+$"))})`